# Download app on someone else's device?

Tags: ipod-touch, find-my-iphone, user-account

If I sign into someone's ipod to download something, using my ID & password and forget to logout, will I be able to locate the device using Find My iphone?

Answer (score 1):

Not unless your Apple ID has been logged in for use with Find My iPhone. Chances are this hasn't happened, since the iPod can only be associated with a single Apple ID  at a time for the purposes of device registration and Find my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you logged into find my iphone with the apple ID